# Language of instruction in the ATER positions in France, and resource for English speaking teaching positions in France that are not postes vacataire

Tags: teaching, job-search, job, france

For ATER positions in France, is the teaching always in French or it depends on the university? I've written to one or two departmental contacts for ATER position, but they replied that the teaching was in French, so I ask.

If I've to look for a teaching position in France at a university level that's not a 'poste de vacataire', what are my options?

**A bit of background if anyone is kind to read:** I'm in a bit of difficult spot as my permit will run out in a couple of months, but I love France and I'd like to stay here. Ideally of course I'm looking for a research position in statistical/mathematical machine learning (more specifically geometric learning) but I'm keeping myself open to teaching positions if the research positions don't show up quickly enough. But the "postes de vacataires" don't usually sponsor a work permit, unlike postdocs and ATER, so my question in general involves resources for teaching positions in English in France at a university level.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, for ATER positions, the teaching is in French. This is essentially due to the fact that for such positions, the majority of the teaching is done  bachelor degree, and the number of classes in English at this level is really low. It is possible that an ATER is in charge of a class at Master level in English, but it will not cover the majority of the teaching duties (96 or 192 hours per year).

There are also ATEN positions ([see](https://universiteouverte.org/2020/09/18/aten-quesaco-un-nouveau-type-de-contrat-precaire-a-luniversite/) here for instance) where you are not supposed to do research, but you have to do 384 hours of teaching.

But there are also some offer of post-doc. Maybe you are already aware of [this site](http://postes.smai.emath.fr/postdoc/).

Answer (score 1):

The only case in which you would teach in English would be if you were an ATER inside a language department and you taught English as a subject.